# Add prefix and namespace in xml not set on correct position XML serialization

Tags: xml, visual-studio, c#-4.0, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces

I am working with a application in that i need to post the xml using SOAP methods a sample of xml is provided us that is below . I used serialization for the xml and but when i post the xml the format of xml is not correct as it is provided us in xml. What i am doing mistake in xml serialization. So the prefix are not displaying on correct position in my xml.

**Sample XML**

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' > 
<SOAP:Body UserGUID = '{3333333-F333-3333-6666-00CDEFGH34555}' > 
 <m:SaveOrder xmlns:m = 'http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/' > 
   <Order UserID = '1' Notes = ' Testing.' CustomerID = '1'  > 
     <Customer /> 
         <Stops >
         <Stop Sequence = '1' StopType = 'P'  > 
        <OrderStopPieces > 
             <OrderStopPiece Sequence = '1' PieceAction = 'P' />
        </OrderStopPieces > 
        </Stop > 
         </Stops >            
   </Order > 
 </m:SaveOrder > 
 </SOAP:Body > 
 </SOAP:Envelope >
```

**My Code is converting the XML**

** Dont Know in edit mode my xml is displaying but not displaying in view mode **
[image: XML IAMGE]

**My class of xml serilization**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public class Envelope
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
            public Body Body { get; set; }

        }

 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Body
    {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "SaveOrder", Namespace = "http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/public/")]
        public SaveOrder SaveOrder { get; set; } 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "UserGUID")]
        public string UserGUID { get; set; }
    }

 public class SaveOrder
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Order")]
        public Order Order { get; set; }
       // [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "m", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
       // public string M { get; set; }
    }

 public class Order
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "UserID")]
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Notes")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "CustomerID")]
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }             
    }
```

My code for setup namespace and prefixes

```
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("SOAP", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    ns.Add("m", "http://www.e-courier.com/software/schema/public/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong namespace associated with the prefix `m:`:

```
   ns.Add("m", "http://www.e-courier.com/software/schema/public/");
```

This never appears in the sample XML.

This should be:

```
   ns.Add("m", "http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/");
```

Note that whether it's rendered with a prefix or not, is irrelevant.

This:

```
 <m:SaveOrder xmlns:m = 'http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/' >
```

Is the same as this:

```
 <SaveOrder xmlns='http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/' >
```

Comment: @GregHNH i changes the code as per your advice but it is generating  <SaveOrder xmlns="http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/public/"> not adding m: in SaveOrder and xmlns:m in xml